# jquery mouseover - unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="portal" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:black" data-target="whatever"></div>

<script>
$('.portal').mouseover({
    console.log($(this).attr('data-target') + ' = zzz');
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an2og43t/

When I run this code I get an `Unexpected token .` SyntaxError. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mouseover takes an event handler](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

> .mouseover(handler)

Your function should look something like this

```
$('.portal').mouseover(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-target') + ' = zzz');
});
```

```js
$('.portal').mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-target') + ' = zzz');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portal" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:black" data-target="whatever"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

missed function()

```
$( ".portal" ).mouseover(function() {
 console.log($(this).attr('data-target') + ' = zzz');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an2og43t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't provided a callback function, instead you pass an object.
The code should be:

```
$('.portal').mouseover(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-target') + ' = zzz');
});
```